# Coolers in videocard

Tags: video, cpu-cooler

Videocard r9 380. In normal mode(surfing ) works 1 cooler on videocard. Does he need to work or no? I know, that 2 coolers turn on with 45 degrees. But I read that in normal mode coolers doesnt work. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GPU fans activate with heat, and adjust their speed accordingly as well.  The threshold for determining speed or number of spinning fans may be set in your BIOS, or using special software such as MSI's AfterBurner (and many more as well).  As long as your temperatures are within range (below 60c) you should not be concerned with the fans.

At least one fan should remain on for temperature control, but if you want passive cooling (no fans on) for noise reduction, you can configure that with an aforementioned fan control program.  Note that even web browsing can use lots of GPU processing, and turning off the fans puts your card at risk of overheating.

If you want to know if your specific card is function as advertised, you should include the manufacturer and model so that it could be verified.  As long as your temperatures are okay, there is no need to be concerned though.